# Google's autocomplete in my form

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete, google-api

I have a form on my website which forwards the textbox input to `www.google.com/search?q=...`. Is there any possibility to get this autocomplete / autofill features google provides when searching over google.com. Firefox uses google's autocomplete function in the search bar next to the url bar, but how can I get this kind of information for my web form?

Comment: Maybe use the Google Custom Search on your site?  http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: jQuery UI has a custom autocomplete, but it's not the same as google.

Comment: google CSE is not an option since I want to forward the user to the orignal google site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was the **Google Suggest API** that allowed to use autocomplete on custom keywords. But it seems google has removed it. But I found out that you can still access the API. There are URLs for JSON and XML.

### JSON

```
http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&q=<your query here>&client=hp
```

### XML

```
http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&q=<your query here>&output=toolbar
```

Without any warranty.

If you want to get autocomplete on a text box. You can combine that with [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: I'm getting the idea these are subject to change without notice, so it's worthwhile adding a web-page monitor on said URL.

Answer (score 3):

Here an complete example with google auto suggest

http://googlesuggest-jquery.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Answer (score 1):

The new url is:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=YOURQUERY

the client part is required; I did't test other clients.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to RickyA´s answer you can filter the suggestion by media using `bs` parameter:

http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow&output=toolbar&ds=

> youtube: ds=yt
>
> books: ds=bo
>
> products: ds=sh
>
> news: ds=n
>
> images: ds=i
>
> web: ds=
>
> recipes: ds=r